# How to assign a value to a mutable reference of an object property?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following :

```js
let data = {
  "world": "bc",
  "d": "ef",
  "g": "hi",
};
let panel = {
  "hello": {
    "world": {},
  }
};
let dataTree = panel.hello;
let exampleBool = true;

if (exampleBool) {
  dataTree = panel.hello.world;
}
Object.assign(dataTree, data);
dataTree.world = "xz";

console.log(dataTree.world);
console.log(data.world);
console.log(data === dataTree);
```

Output :

```
xz
bc
false
```

Desired output :

```
xz
xz
true
```

I would like to set a value to the object property referenced by `dataTree`, which can change depending on `exampleBool`.
I would like to link the object referenced by `data` be the same as `dataTree`, in other word makes `dataTree === data` to be `true`.

The problem with `Object.assign` is that it makes a copy of each property in `data` and in my case, `data` keys can be a thousands length so I don't want to clone each ones.

Any way to do this in JS ?

Comment: What's wrong with `data = dataTree;`? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5zsuwce0/

Comment: @jabaa That's a single assignment to a field-style property. The OP wants the `data` property to behave like a computed-property, not a field.

Comment: OP: Why do you want to do this? Generally speaking _side effects are bad_ and you cannot really express this in a static-typing system like TypeScript.

Comment: I'm in fact using this in a typescript project and make use of the non-typed aspect of the JS to make `dataTree` a reference to a property in a recursive object tree.
@jabaa yes like @Dai said, at the end I only need the `panel` object.

Comment: You could use getters, setters or proxies to create computed properties but I don't see computed properties in the question. AFAIK the only way to achieve `data === dataTree` is to make both point to the same object and since these two variables aren't properties, you can't use getters or proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to set a value to the object property referenced by `dataTree`

The variable `dataTree` is not a reference to an object property. There is no such thing in JS. `dataTree` does reference the `{ "world": {} }` object (or, after the conditional assignment, the `{}` object), and that's it. You cannot mutate the property where you get the object from through the variable.

Instead, store the base object and the property name:

```js
let data = {
  "world": "bc",
  "d": "ef",
  "g": "hi",
};
let panel = {
  "hello": {
    "world": {},
  }
};
let dataTreeBase = panel,
    dataTreeProp = "hello";
let exampleBool = true;

if (exampleBool) {
  dataTreeBase = panel.hello;
  dataTreeProp = "world";
}
dataTreeBase[dataTreeProp] = data;
dataTreeBase[dataTreeProp].world = "xz";

console.log(dataTreeBase[dataTreeProp].world);
console.log(data.world);
console.log(data === dataTreeBase[dataTreeProp]);
```

Of course there are various ways to abstract this in functions or objects with getters/setters or methods, but you cannot achieve this with just a plain variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `dataTree` to `data`:

```js
let data = {
  "world": "bc",
  "d": "ef",
  "g": "hi",
};
let panel = {
  "hello": {
    "world": {},
  }
};
let dataTree = panel.hello;
let exampleBool = true;

if (exampleBool) {
  dataTree = panel.hello.world;
}
data = dataTree;
dataTree.world = "xz";

console.log(dataTree.world);
console.log(data.world);
console.log(data === dataTree);
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to use Object.assign as it makes a copy of each property. I edited the code snippet and the desired output

Comment: @Raphiki You can even remove the `Object.assign`.